# how is a before filter called from a route on the router instance in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

[from the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#controller-filters)
I can call it like this

```
Route::get('profile', array('before' => 'auth',
            'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'));
```

The router will create the Route with the property  `before`

In `Route->run` the following is called

```
list($name, $params) = $this->parseFilter($name, $params);

if ( ! is_null($callable = $this->router->getFilter($name)))
{
   return call_user_func_array($callable, $params);
}
```

My question is: How does the Router know the name of the filter.  I follow the createRoute method?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are asking about Laravel 4.0, just by guessing from the code snippet you have provided. The code in the `Routing` module is changed quite a bit in Laravel 4.1.

The Router knows the name of the filter because router keep that data!.

Let's start with the creating before filter. When creating `before` filter `before()` method in route class called.

```
public function before()
{
    $this->setBeforeFilters(func_get_args());

    return $this;
}
```

In this function, parameters are read by [func_get_args](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php%20func_get_args) function.

Then filter name and filter parameters is set to the internal data store using `setBeforeFilters` method.

I hope this answers your question. (If I understood it correctly)

Comment: yes, I sort of get how it is internally stored. It's a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entiely sure on what you are asking - but Laravel has two filters - `before` and `after`.

Before filters are run before your route is called. You can attach as many filters to your `before` as you desire - like this: `'before' => 'auth|other|example'`. In this case it will run `auth`, `other` and `example` (in that order).

You can do exactly the same thing with your `after` filters.

This filters can be applied in the routes file like in your example

```
Route::get('profile', array('before' => 'auth',
            'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'));
```

Or they can be applied inside a controller if that is where you perfer

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->beforeFilter('auth');
    }
}
```

You can also specifically in the controller filters that the filters only apply to specific routes

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));
}
```

Or you can say it applies on all routes except specific routes

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('except' => 'post'));
}
```

Comment: I believe OP is quite familiar with how to use the filters. His question is more about the inner workings of the routing/filters.

Comment: As I said - I'm not entirely sure what he is asking - the question can be interpreted in a number of ways. So I'm trying to provide as much info on routing and filters as I can.